# Check if the data in datagridview is empty or null

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I have a problem, probably you guys in this forum could help me.

Here is my problem:

I want to show the MessageBox that say there is no data in datagridview, you cannot delete it.
I already can delete the data in the datagridview, but when the datagridview contains 0 data, and i click delete "button", it is error. The error is: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NullReferenceException`

Here is the code that pointed by the error:
`int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;`

Here is the code:

```
private void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable) dataGridView1.DataSource;
    int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ID"]);
    dt.DefaultView[rowNum].Delete();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        if (choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
            sound.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");

            if (rowNum == 0)
            {
                bool rowIsEmpty = true;

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        rowIsEmpty = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (rowIsEmpty)
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Tidak ada Data di Baris ini!", "Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    Delete(sender, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridView.CurrentRow` is **usable** only when you set `DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`. Otherwise you have to get the current row by this:

```
int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum];
```

### UPDATE

Looks like that you use a `DataTable` as DataSource for your `dataGridView1`, you should take the benefit of `Adapter` in `ADO.NET`. This code is just some modifying your current code which in fact updates data in 2 phases: 1. Remove row from DataTable as well as from DataGridView  2. Remove the actual row in database.

```
    private void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
        if(rowNum == -1) {
           MessageBox.Show("There is no row selected!");
           return;
        }
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ID"]);
        //check if row is empty, simply return
        if(IsRowEmpty(rowNum)){
          System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
          sounds.Play();
          MessageBox.Show("There is no data in the selected row", "Error");
          return;
        }
        //Remove the row
        dt.DefaultView[rowNum].Delete();
        dt.AcceptChanges(); //<-- Because you don't use Adapter, call this to restore the row state.
        //Remove the underlying row in database
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [ID] = @ID";
            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            if (choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");                    
            }
         }
    }
    //method to check if a row is empty
    private bool IsRowEmpty(int index){
       return dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                                       .All(c=>c.Value == null);
    }
```

Comment: hai, already tried your code, but the rowNum is -1. why is it like that? I clicked the row that has no data.

Comment: @Kaoru it's strange, it doesn't matter whether the row has data or not, what do you mean by `row has no data`? does it have all the cells being empty?

Comment: ya, all the cells are empty, either i click the row or not, it still error, index was out of range and the value of rowNum is -1.

All the cells are empty, because i haven't input any data in that datagridview.

Comment: @Kaoru normally `CurrentCellAddress.Y` can't be `-1` anyway. Unless your `DataGridView` doesn't have any cell selected, but you said even you clicked on the cell. That's very strange.

Comment: after below this code `MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");`, do i need keep that code or just delete it?

Comment: @Kaoru that is just to show message box to inform the user that `row has been deleted`, however **you should place that code after the actual row deleting code**.

Comment: i mean, after below this code `MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");`, do i need to keep those code? i think the problem is on there.

Comment: @Kaoru looks like you use `Recursion` to delete all the empty rows (or non-empty rows?)? That's not very suitable for your case while you can use a simple loop.

Comment: What do you mean by `Recursion` @King King?

Comment: @Kaoru `Recursion` means you call a method right in its body. It will make some kind of loop but is based on `call stack`. It's useful only when we don't know the count of loops beforehand or when the `logic` is needed to make clear.

Comment: Thanks! How about my problem then @King King?

Comment: @Kaoru I still don't get what you want, do you want to delete all the empty rows or all the non-empty rows?

Comment: I already can delete all of the non-empty rows. And for the empty rows when the user click delete button --> `"this come out in my mind "what happens if the user click the "Delete" button when there is no data in that selected row? (All the rows all empty and yet the user click the "Delete" button)"`. When it is like that, i want make an exception, and the message box will appear and say `Cannot be deleted, there is no data in this row!`

Comment: @Kaoru do you want to delete all the rows by 1 click on `Delete button` or just the `selected row`? (of course if it's empty, show the message instead)

Comment: 1. if the user click the "Delete" button, the data in selected row will be deleted (Only Selected Row Will be Deleted) otherwise show the message, "You haven't selected any rows" <-- if the user haven't click any rows. 2. And/Or if the user select rows that has no data in that row, show the message "There is no data in this row".

Number 1 solved now.

Comment: Only the selected rows will be deleted, and if the selected rows has data. (Done) If not, show the message "There is no data in this row". (Still in Progress)

Comment: Hai, when i select the row that has data, it show the message "There is no data in this row", even though it have data. And, when i click the "Delete" button in row 7 (have data), error says: "Index was out of range, must be less than or non - negative"

Comment: @Kaoru it's a mistake, it's `rowNum` passed in `IsRowEmpty` not `id`, I corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks, it is worked. But i have one more problem, when there is no data in the selected row, the error says: `Index -1 is either negative or above rows count.` and it is pointed in `int id = ....`, rowNum is `-1`

Comment: @Kaoru we just need to check if `rowNum == -1` then show some message and return. However I think it can't be `-1` unless your `DataGridView` doesn't have any row.

Comment: i already did that, but it is still cannot. Still have the error. But, why there is -1 when there is no data in the selected row? --"

Comment: @Kaoru I can't help you more, it's **obviously** to me that **CurrentCellAddress.Y** can't be `-1` unless **there isn't any row** in your `DataGridView`, once your `DataGridView` has at least 1 row, the `CurrentCell` is always **specified** and `CurrentCellAddress.Y` is always not `-1`. If you still get `-1`, I can't understand why and can't help. BTW, you might not know how to handle the case `rowNum=-1`, see the code I updated.

Comment: i already knew how to handle `rowNum == -1`. Anyway, thanks for your answer. Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this dt.Rows.count > 0 means that there is data  in data table if not there is no data in datatable , if data was present you can do your operation . dt.Rows.count will give the rows count in data table

Answer (score 0):

I found the following condition quite useful

```
if(dataGridView1.DataSource!=null)
{
    // do something
}
```